# How to group set of users in cohort of 10 in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I'm using the following query to bifurcate the users based on how many times they triggered a specific event. I want the users to be grouped in cohort of 10 for instance, number of users who have triggered the events 0-10 times or 11-20 times. Also, the user should belong to a specific cohort and must not be included in more than one.

```
SELECT COUNT(event_names) AS asset_no, id
FROM
  `abc`
WHERE
   app_store = "iTunes"
AND version = "2.5"
  AND (date between "20191116" AND "20191122") 
  AND event_names IN ("asset")
  AND id IN
  (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT id
    FROM
      `xyz`
    WHERE
      event_names = "internet"
      AND internet_status = "1"
  ) 
GROUP BY
  id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [RANGE_BUCKET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket) function

In a table called students, check to see how many records would exist in each age_group bucket, based on a student's age:

- age_group 0 (age < 10)
- age_group 1 (age >= 10, age < 20)
- age_group 2 (age >= 20, age < 30)
- age_group 3 (age >= 30)

.

```
WITH students AS
(
  SELECT 9 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 25 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 31 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 32 AS age UNION ALL
  SELECT 33 AS age
)
SELECT RANGE_BUCKET(age, [10, 20, 30]) AS age_group, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM students
GROUP BY 1

+--------------+-------+
| age_group    | count |
+--------------+-------+
| 0            | 1     |
| 2            | 2     |
| 3            | 3     |
+--------------+-------+
```

For your query it could be like:

```
with t (
..your query here
)
SELECT RANGE_BUCKET(asset_no, [10, 20, 30]) AS asset_group, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM t
    GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Is there a way to provide alias for asset_group(i.e 0, 1, 2) for different buckets?

Comment: You need to write that as an outer query, with a case/when syntax.